# Как записать данные из TextBox в List

Tags: c#, winforms, list, textbox

У меня есть форма, которая предназначена для сбора данных о человеке. Собранную информацию необходимо сохранить в List, чтобы в дальнейшем можно было обращаться к конкретному элементу.

Есть следующий код:

```
public class Person //создаем класс для данных
    {
        public string First_Name;
        public string Second_Name;
        public int Age;                        
    }
    public class AddList //класс для создания списка
    {
        string First_Name, Second_Name;
        int Age;
        public List<Person> Persons = new List<Person>();
    }

        public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) //определенный textBox записывает и содержит определенную информацию
    {
        new Person().First_Name = Convert.ToString(textBox1.Text);
    }

    private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        new Person().Second_Name = Convert.ToString(textBox2.Text);
    }

    private void textBox3_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        new Person().Age = Convert.ToInt32(textBox3.Text);
    }
```

После того, как пользователь ввел все данные, он нажимает на кнопку "Ввод". После нажатия этой кнопки введенная информация должна добавиться в список. И здесь у меня возникает вопрос: **как это сделать?**

Я попробовал реализовать это следующим образом, но выдает ошибку:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Product.Add(textBox1.Text, textBox2.Text, textBox3.Text, textBox4.Text);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот решение

```
   public class AddList //класс для создания списка
{
    string First_Name, Second_Name;
    int Age;
    public List<Person> Persons = new List<Person>();

   public void add(TextBox textBox1, TextBox textBox2, TextBox textBox3) // метод для добавления
    {
        Person p = new Person
        {
            First_Name = textBox1.Text,
            Second_Name = textBox2.Text,
            Age = Convert.ToInt32(textBox3.Text)

        };
        Persons.Add(p);
    }
}


    AddList MyList = new AddList();// создаем экземпляр класса
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MyList.add(Texbox1,Texbox2,Textbox3); // добавляем данные из textbox
    }
```

Comment: Отредактировал всё ровно так, как Вы написали, выделяет строку с MyList.add (именно add) ошибкой: Form2.AddList.add(TextBox, TextBox, TextBox) недоступен из-за его уровня защиты

Comment: добавил `public`

Comment: Спасибо, теперь все работает!